# Offloading behaviour into another class

Tags: java, oop

Let us assume I have a class A. By the time, my class grows and for not violating the single responsibility principle I want to offload some functionality into a helper class. Is it then correct to do the following in A:

`int foo() { B b = new B(this); return b.complexCalculation() + 100; }`

The problem I have with it is that A is directly responsible for its dependencies. Moreover, I am wondering how to test this, since I cannot mock the B instance.

Thank you.

Comment: In this case, as `B` encapsulates behaviour required by `A` it might be a good idea to create and interface (`ComplexCalculation`) to implement `B` against (`MockComplexCalculation` `ImginaryComplexCalcuation` etc) and then add `B` as part of `A` constructor.  Of course you then might be in violation of other principles like the Law of Demeter.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that implementation of `B` does not going to change, you can do as what you have done. But in a ideal world, this approach does not support scaling and testing as you are coupling `B` with `A`. The better approach would be pass `B` as a dependency while creating `A`, there by making `A` loosely coupled. Also always use interface for injecting dependencies, so you can have multiple implementations. Code for abstraction not for implementation.

```
interface B{
  int complexCalculation();
}

class B1 implements B {
    @Override
    public int complexCalculation(){
       // implementation 1
    }
}
class B2 implements B {
    @Override
    public int complexCalculation(){
       // implementation 2
    }
}

class A {
   B b;
   
   public A(B b){
     this.b = b;
   }

   int foo(){
     return b.complexCalculation();
   }

}

A a = new A(new B1());
//or
A a = new A(new B2());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And is it ok then, that I have an instance variable of A which I only need for that one method? I mean if I start adding more functionalities that I have to offload to other interfaces (C, D, E, ...), then I would end up with storing a reference to that C, D and E instances in A, right? Is it ok or is it indicating a bad design?

Comment: If `B`, `C` and `D` encapsulates a single responsibility (i.e The Single Responsibility Principle) I see no issue. However an excessive number of classes with a singe method, all used by a single class might indicate a design issue, in such a case I might look at using interfaces or "Functions" to represent `B`, `C` and `D` as a better fit.  Be guided by the readability/maintainability of your code.  You will read your code more than you write it.  Starting with classes is a good first step, it keeps your options open, they may have a single method today but tomorrow they may have more.